# ASP.NET: Static dictionary empty after response.redirect

Tags: c#, asp.net, dictionary, response.redirect

I am facing an issue regarding a static dictionary which seems to be emptied by a "response.redirect" command.

Here is the main page's code :

```
public partial class Accueil : System.Web.UI.Page
{
    protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    { ... }

    protected void _Connect_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        PlayerDao.LogIn(_Pseudo.Text, _Password.Text, HttpContext.Current.Session.SessionID);
        Response.Redirect("~/Game/Index.aspx", true);
    }
}
```

The LogIn mehod extract:

```
public static void LogIn(string pseudo, string password, string sessionId)
{
    ...
    Player.Dict.Add(sessionId, player);
    ...
}
```

And the Player.Dict dictionary:

```
public class Player
{
    private static Dictionary<string, Player> dict = new Dictionary<string, Player>();
    public static Dictionary<string, Player> Dict
    {
        get { return dict; }
        set { dict= value; }
    }

    ...
}
```

Right before the Response.Redirect, the dictionary still contains the element added in the LogIn method, but in the Index.aspx Page_Load code, it is empty.
If anyone has an idea please feel free, I must have done a silly mistake but can't figure it out.

Thanks !

Comment: Isn't that how the HTTP protocol works at all? Not familiar with ASP.NET that much, but unless you run on application server, you will loose any data in memory after jumping through pages.

Comment: @RoyalBg yes irregardless of asp.net, this is how it works.  OP needs some sort of persistance such as session (if its for a user) or database (if its global).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Flash_Back, keep in mind that the web is stateless.  Meaning that your dictionary is being created in memory on the server.  When you redirect to a new page, your context is that of a new request so the dictionary is gone.  The only thing that you can access during the page_load event for the new page is something that you create during the page_load or, something that has been stored in Session or in a state database.  If it's information specific to a single user, use Session.  If it's something to be shared by all users of the application (as it looks like your dictionary is meant to be) you need to persist that data, possibly in a database.

I am answering in the context of a single web server scenario.  Session becomes a bad solution to this problem when your application spans multiple web servers.  In that case, use a database.

Comment: Thanks a lot for your answer Mike ! I'm quite novice, but the thing I wanted the achieve was to store the users sessions somehow, in order to get the player object back from database using the sessionId. Since it seems impossible to be done with a static dictionary, should it be stored in the databse, in a table which would associate a user id and a session id ?

Comment: For what you're doing I'd say yes, a database table is the way to go.  If your application doesn't already use one for its own data, there are lightweight options to consider.  I use MongoLab (MongoDB as a service) for any web app that won't generate a ton of data.  They offer free databases up to 500MB and there is a C# driver you can get through Nuget.  It's quick and easy to setup and use (after a short learning curve) and you have a new tool in your kit for the future.

Comment: I already do have a database for the website, but I didn't think that creating a table for users sessions was actually the right way. However, since the sessionId is not meant to change during the user connection, sounds pretty good after all ! Thanks a lot for your help, I will accept your answer.

Comment: If I may ask a last thing, creating a table means that a request will be sent in every Page_Load, in order to get the player related to the sessionId. Wouldn't it be quite slow with lots of users connected simultaneously ?

Comment: Yes, it certainly could, depending on what you mean by 'lots'.  To cut down on unnecessary db traffic you could retrieve the value and store it in Session.  Then during each page_load event check if the value is in session.  If not, make the call to the database to retrieve it (and store it for the next call).